# Какие знаки препинания поставить?

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте, уважаемые лингвисты и филологи. Мне надо написать в одном предложении Играть, чтобы жить: Клан. Где "Играть, чтобы жить" - название серии/цикла. "Клан" - название книги. Какие знаки препинания между ними ставятся? Заранее благодарна.

Comment: *Летать, чтобы жить* :   
***Баклан***  


![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/Vz7iOd4.jpg

Comment: @Rubina, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

В русской традиции рекомендаций по оформлению таких составных названий пока нет.

В английской есть варианты "Играть, чтобы жить. Клан" или "Играть, чтобы жить: Клан".
Чаще все английскими правилами и пользуются.

Answer (score 0):

Тут зависит от того, что Вы хотите подчеркнуть в первую очередь: цикл или название книги. Вариантов может быть много. Например, так: "Клан" (серия "Играть, чтобы жить"). Либо, если Вы перечисляете книги этого цикла, можно оформить так:
Серия "Играть, чтобы жить":
"Клан",
и далее перечисление всех книг цикла.